# JavaScript function not working properly on load, but working when called afterwards

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have built a little sidebar with HTML and CSS that looks something like this:

```
<body>
<div class='sidebar'>

<div class='sidebar-buttons-section'>

<button class='sidebar-button' id='search'>
...
</button>

<button class='sidebar-button' id='account'>
...
</button>

<!-- and so on ... -->
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

I wanted the `sidebar-button-section` to align to the center vertically, so I made a JavaScript function which does exactly that. I used this code to get the exact value for the top margin:

```
(document.documentElement.clientHeight - sideBarElement.offsetHeight) / 2;
```

I put that into a function called `verticalAlign()` and then used two commands to ensure it's working properly:

```
verticalAlign();// call for the first time
window.onresize = verticalAlign; // align the sidebar
                                 // everytime the window is resized
```

When I loaded the HTML something strange happened. The first thing I saw, was this:
[Sidebar when the page is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86uHW.png)

The margin is too much and it's not perfectly aligned.
When I resize the page however, this happens:
[Sidebar alignments when the page is resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Boyz7.png)

The buttons are all perfectly aligned as they should be.
Why does the function not work properly when I call it for the first time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best guess is that images haven't loaded yet at that point so the heights are not correct. Although this is something that could/should be done with CSS instead of JS.

Comment: Alright I'll try to do it with CSS.

Comment: I figured out a way of doing it with CSS. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way of doing it with CSS:
I needed to add this code to the `.sidebar` element.

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

That's a better way to do it since it doesn't require any JavaScript.